# Django view not saving to model

Tags: python, django

I have a view I am calling when a user clicks a button on the site, it pulls JSON data(from the Coinbase API) and converts it to a string and should **save the string pulled to the current user's account**.

Whenever they click the button it will pull the string, but nothing is saved to the account, which is the issue.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from ico_login.models import UserAddress 
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client


@login_required()
def generate_address_btc(request, *args, **kwargs):
    client = Client('api', 'key')
    r = client.get_addresses('account_id')
    address = r['data'][0]['address']
    request.user.address = str(address)
    request.user.save()

    return HttpResponse(address)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=' ')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from ico_details import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('create_address/', views.generate_address_btc, name='generate')
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view you write `request.user.address = ...`, so you add the attribute `address` to a `User` object. As far as I read your code, this is not what you want. You would like to put `str(address)` into the field `address` of the object `UserAddress` related to the `User` object from `request.user`, right?!

So, here are the suggested edits to do so:

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserAddress(models.Model):
    # next line changed
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_address')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=' ')
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from ico_login.models import UserAddress 
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client


@login_required()
def generate_address_btc(request, *args, **kwargs):
    client = Client('api', 'key')
    r = client.get_addresses('account_id')
    address = r['data'][0]['address']
    # next 2 lines changed
    request.user.user_address.address = str(address)
    request.user.user_address.save()

return HttpResponse(address)
```

*Hope that helped and happy coding!*

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you, I've been staring at this for hours!